# Using AES_DECRYPT in SELECT Query Builder - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to decrypt the data from mysql database provided by our partner.
They encrypted it using this in mysql `AES_ENCRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'somekey')))`

In my case, I'm trying to use the `AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'somekey'))) as f1` in my laravel code.

Like this:

```
$query = DB::connection('db2')->table('tbsample')->select("fld_id", "AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'somekey')))")->get();
```

And I'm getting this kind of error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'RA3019')))' in 'field list' (SQL: select `fld_id`, `AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'RA3019')))` from `tbsample`)
```

I've been searching how to use the AES_Decrypt in my query but luck is not on my side. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\DB::raw()` or `selectRaw`:

```php
$query = DB::connection('db2')->table('tbsample')->select("fld_id", \DB::raw("AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'somekey')))"))->get();
```

Or

```php
$query = DB::connection('db2')->table('tbsample')->selectRaw("fld_id, AES_DECRYPT(fld_code, md5(CONCAT(fld_id, 'somekey')))")->get();
```

Comment: YES! Worked Like a charm. By the way I tried using the 2nd option you provided. Thank you so much!

Comment: Will accept your answer. But it says `You can accept an answer in 4 minutes`. I'll try again after 4minutes :)